# Using Array In jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I want to use array instead of using

```
if(imageExtension == 'jpg' || imageExtension == 'png' || imageExtension == 'gif' ). C
```

Can someone please give me a clue :D

```
setupChangeImage : function() {
        $('.carousel li a').each(function(){
            $(this).click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var src = $(this).attr('href');
                var dataSource = $(this).data('src');
                var imageExtension = dataSource.substr(dataSource.length-3, 3);             
                if (src != $('.gallery img.gallery-main-image,.main-image .main-image-first').attr('src').replace(/\?(.*)/,'')){
                    $('.gallery img.gallery-main-image,.main-image .main-image-first,.main-image-last').stop().animate({
                        opacity: '0'
                    }, function(){
                        $('.loading').show();
                        $(this).attr('src', src);
                        $('.main-image-second').remove();
                        if(imageExtension == 'jpg' || imageExtension == 'png' || imageExtension == 'gif' ){
                            var imageLast = '<div class="main-image-second"><img class="main-image-last" src="'+ dataSource +'" alt="" /></div>';
                            $('.main-image').append(imageLast);
                        }
                        else {
                            var iframe = '<div class="main-image-second"><iframe class="main-image-last" width="657" height="432" src="'+ dataSource +'" style="border:none;margin-top:14px;" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0"></iframe></div>';
                            $('.main-image').append(iframe);
                        }
                    }).load(function(){
                        $('.loading').hide();
                        $(this).stop().animate({
                            opacity: '1'
                                                                                       });                      
                });
                }           
            });
        });
        }
```

Comment: `/^(jpg|png|gif|)$/.test(imageextension)` if you are interested in regex.

Comment: jquery has inArray - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

Comment: It's **well worth** spending an hour reading through the jQuery API. That's all the time it takes, and it pays you back *massively*.

Answer (score 3):

```
var arr = ["jpg", "png","gif" ];
if(jQuery.inArray(imageExtension, arr) !== -1){
//found 
}else{
//not found 
}
```

refer http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

Answer (score 0):

This will work without jQuery.

```
if (['jpg', 'png', 'gif'].indexOf(imageExtension) > -1) ...
```

Run this somewhere on the page to make it work in IE8:

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function indexOf(search) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            if (this[i] === search) return i;
        }
        return -1;
    };
}
```

You might as well use jQuery I guess.

Comment: Note that IE8, which is a very popular browser (about 23% of global browser users use it), doesn't support `Array#indexOf`. Since the OP is using jQuery, jQuery's `inArray` (as suggested by SAM and, briefly, myself) is the better choice.